GEE model with/without interaction - interpretation
I measured a new biomarker during a therapy (at several timepoints). Clinical data for all patients is present at baseline. Now I am using a GEE model with an exploratory approach to identify clinical variables with an effect on the biomarker during therapy.
I tested every clinical variable in a separate GEE model, with the biomarker being the dependent variable, and taking the factor time and the clinical variable in the model.
I also tested every clinical variable the same way, but also including the interaction between time and the clinical variable. Now I don't understand why there are some clinical variables with a main effect, but with including the interaction time/clinical variable other clinical variables with a main effect are appearing.
Which way would be the best to identify clinical variables with an effect on the biomarker - using a model only with factor time and clinical variable, or do I always have to include the interaction?

This is formulated in an overly abstract way. Please tell us what is the biomarker, what is the clinical variables?
